# Show/hide css class by url parameter with php

Tags: php, css, class, hide, show

I'm using an open source PHP CMS and I can show/hide side modules by menu item. The problem I have is that I want to show/hide modules on pages that are not part a menu item (ie step 2 in a registration process), and that is not a function that the CMS provides.

How can I show/hide css classes by url parameters?

Comment: @VladPreda It isn't vague at all... It's actually quite concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by $_GET

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['param']) && $_GET['param'] ==youwant){  ?>

//css

<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fairly easy

`.CLASSNAME {
     display:none
}